# tsql date if statement not working as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to filter out some events that occur during a specific time.  I have tried many variations but I cannot get the filter to work as expected.  The below is meant to send alert when it falls outside of time range from yesterday/today at 10.30pm and 7.30 in the morning

for example if the event occurs at 11:34pm.  It should fall into the IF= "do nothing" but it falls into the Else
Example date failing: DATE/TIME: 01/04/2024 23:34:42

```
DECLARE @actionTime  as smalldatetime = getdate() --dateadd(hour, -16, getdate())
DECLARE @startTime as smalldatetime, @endTime as smalldatetime
--select @startTime = ' 22:00:00', @endTime = ' 07:30:00'
select @startTime = DATEADD(hh,22,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate() - 1), 0)),
  @endTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, DATEADD(hh,7,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)))
print @actionTime
print @endTime
print @startTime

--IF ('2024-01-04 11:34PM' between '2024-01-03 10:00PM' and '2024-01-04 7:30AM')
--IF ('2024-01-04 23:34' between '2024-01-03 22:00' and '2024-01-04 07:30')
IF (@actionTime >= @startTime and @actionTime <= @endTime)
BEGIN
    --Do nothing.
    print  'Ignore Alert'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'Sending Alert'
END
```

Comment: You can just add 90 minutes and then see it that result is before 9:00am.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `2024-01-03 22:00` <= `2024-01-04 23:34` <= `2024-01-04 07:30`? I'd say that `@actionTime` is after the end of that range, hence control transfers to the `else` clause. Aside: When you call `GetDate()` in separate statements you are likely to collect different values to play with. Starting with `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and then using `@Now` as needed can avoid some annoying problems.

Comment: I've just tested the code (on SQL Server 2016 as you did not state what version) and it seems to be working as expected? Here's a fiddle to demonstrate. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qu2y1Crt)

You stated a "failing" date but did not show how you tested that. Make sure you use an unambiguous date format when testing (which is certainly not the US date format).

Comment: Side note: It is unusual to use `<=` for the end of a date/time range. This can cause edge-case data to show up in two adjacent ranges. For example, if one range included `2024-01-03 22:00 <= @actionTime <= 2024-01-04 07:30` and another included `2024-01-04 07:30 <= @actionTime <= 2024-01-04 15:00`, a row with `@actionTime <= 2024-01-04 07:30` would be included in both. This is avoided if you use `<` for the date/time end test. `@actionTime>= @startTime and @actionTime < @endTime`. (This logic also applies to whole-day ranges, where the close of the end-date is actually 00:00 of the next day.)

Comment: Actually I think was has been failing is when you're trying to test out a time between 10:30pm and midnight. Obviously the *current* time today is never going to fall in yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the end point should be included in the range?

Either way, it's easy to slide your range by 90 minutes so you only need a single time comparison with no need to worry about date components:

```
if cast(dateadd(minute, 90, getdate()) as time) <= cast('09:00am' as time)
begin
    ...
end
```

Or you can ignore the 90-minute adjustment and compare both sections separately:

```
if cast(getdate() as time) >= cast('10:30pm' as time) or
   cast(getdate() as time) <= cast('07:30am' as time)
```

You could also use `not between`, with the complication of tweaking the end points, which has the benefit of not repeating the non-literal expression which is sometimes useful. Of course the first option has the same feature as well:

```
if cast(getdate() as time) not between
    cast('3:24:59.9999999pm' as time) and cast('10:29:59.9999999pm' as time)
```

soapbox: There are some advocates of avoiding all uses of `between` because somehow professional software developers are not capable of grasping how discrete types like `integer`/`date` work versus more finely-precise values as `decimal`/`datetime`. Their one legitimate point is that you should often use a half-open interval for these kinds of ranges. /soapbox

I should have realized sooner that what you were experiencing is that your logic would never pass the test when the time portion was 10:30pm up to midnight (which is also why you were using the snippets that were commented out: to fake out the current time.) While you can easily calculate a range that includes a portion of yesterday, clearly a date + time coming out of `getdate()` can never fall outside of today.

Comment: The OP appears to want to ignore date/times from _yesterday_ at 10:30pm to _today_ at 7:30am. Checking only the time without validating the date causes _today_ at 11:00pm to to be treated the same as _yesterday_ at 11:00pm. Aside: Using a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Definitions_and_terminology) avoids fiddling with the precisions of various date/time datatypes and having code break with occasional errors when a datatype is changed.

Comment: @HABO The date is irrelevant. OP is really just checking to see what portion of the day the event -- that just happened -- occurs. Since `getdate()` is involved it just seemed natural to do a time comparison ranging from a date+time starting "last night" and running through "this morning." Also I started off by asking about the inclusive end points and then mentioned half-open intervals later on as well.

Comment: I'm surprised that no-one has posted a "might be an X-Y problem" comment, but that may be the case here. If the OP wishes to configure the system to not wake anybody up in the middle of the night when the overpressure sensors trip or the feedwater pump fails, then the logic only really needs to check the time.. That is the X. The Y is trying to define an hopping date/time range for this purpose.

Comment: @TN Yeah, that's an interesting perspective. It's always good to look for elegant solutions, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  This solution has worked great for me and has simplified my code greatly.   your logic makes a lot of sense.  FYI.  I was using between but for the sake of other articles I found changed it to rule out any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
-- Calculate @startTime as yesterday at 10:30 PM
SET @startTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, DATEADD(HOUR, 22, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)))

-- Calculate @endTime as today at 7:30 AM
SET @endTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server 2022, you can use DATETRUNC() combined with a single DATEADD() to calculate your start/end times.

```
SET @startTime = DATEADD(minute, -1440 + 22 * 60 + 30, DATETRUNC(day, GETDATE()))
SET @endTime = DATEADD(minute, 7 * 60 + 30, DATETRUNC(day, GETDATE()))
```

(-1440 minutes is one day back.)